# Smart Group for Soft Credit Name

Tags: search, smartgroups

Is there a way to create a smart group that contains contacts that have made a contribution with a specific soft credit name?  I see that I can run a Soft Credit Report and add contacts to a group but I would like to make that group dynamic.  We're using Civi 4.7.17.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Jon G - Megaphone Tech](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/users/12) has written an extension [Soft Credit Custom Fields](https://github.com/MegaphoneJon/com.megaphonetech.softcreditcustomfields) which, amongst other things, adds a "Soft Creditee's Name" field to the Advanced Search. This should be used to create the smart group.

**Edited**: *SearchKit into the scene*

Note that with SearchKit it's possible to create the smart group without the help of the extension:

```
[
  [
    "SavedSearch",
    "save",
    {
      "records": [
        {
          "name": "Fundraisers_P2P",
          "label": "Fundraisers P2P",
          "api_entity": "Contact",
          "api_params": {
            "version": 4,
            "select": [
              "id",
              "sort_name",
              "contact_type:label",
              "contact_sub_type:label",
              "GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT Contact_ContributionSoft_contact_id_01.soft_credit_type_id:label) AS GROUP_CONCAT_Contact_ContributionSoft_contact_id_01_soft_credit_type_id_label"
            ],
            "orderBy": [],
            "where": [
              [
                "Contact_ContributionSoft_contact_id_01.soft_credit_type_id:name",
                "=",
                "pcp"
              ]
            ],
            "groupBy": [
              "id"
            ],
            "join": [
              [
                "ContributionSoft AS Contact_ContributionSoft_contact_id_01",
                "INNER",
                [
                  "id",
                  "=",
                  "Contact_ContributionSoft_contact_id_01.contact_id"
                ]
              ]
            ],
            "having": []
          }
        }
      ],
      "match": [
        "name"
      ]
    }
  ]
]
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe advanced search will be able to do this for you.  (Main menu, Search and then Advanced Search)

Below the basic search fields you should find a collapsed section for Contributions.  Expand it and you'll see a pull down for Contributions or Soft Credits.  When you select one of the soft credit options, you'll get an additional option to select soft credit type.   After you've pressed search, you can create a smart group in the normal manor (click on All XXX records, select New Smart Group from the Actions pull down, give it a name, etc.).

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Yes, this would definitely give me a great way to search for a specific Soft Credit Type but unfortunately this isn't what I am looking for.  The very first line of the Soft Credits report filter lets me filter for specific soft credit names.  I was hoping to see a similar functionality in the Advanced Search tool and then create a smart group, just like you had explained.